# z-index not working for image behind wordpress menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, position, z-index

I am trying to put an image behind my header and menu. I set all of the layers above the background image div including all of the menu elements to `position:relative;z-index:10;` and the div with the background image to `position:relative;z-index:0;`

you can see my code here: http://wheresuccessblooms.com/wordpress/

I know it has something to do with the menu because when I delete the call to the menu the background image goes to where it should. Not sure what else I need to set the position and z-index to? PULLING MY HAIR OUT. lol Please help.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16">
      <a href="http://wheresuccessblooms.com/wordpress/contact-us/">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17">
        <a href="http://wheresuccessblooms.com/wordpress/contact-us/">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15">
        <a href="http://wheresuccessblooms.com/wordpress/contact-us/">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

                        <div id="top_slider">
                            <div id="slider">
                                <div id="slider_wrap">

                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
```

CSS: JUST THE MENU AND SLIDER CSS

```
nav{position:relative;z-index:5;}
div.menu-main-menu-container{position:relative;z-index:5;}
ul#menu-main-menu{position:relative;z-index:5;}
li.menu-item{position:relative;z-index:5;}
#page_nav {width:100%; height:53px;background-color:#f27479;position:relative;z-index:10;}
#page_nav ul { float: left; display: block;position:relative;z-index:5;}
#page_nav ul li { float: left; list-style-type: none; margin-top:20px;border-right:1px solid #ca6064;position:relative;z-index:5;}
#page_nav ul li a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 700; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5); padding-left: 20px;position:relative;z-index:5; }
#page_nav ul li a:hover { color: #a2a2a2; position:relative;z-index:5;}
#page_nav ul li.current a, 
#page_nav ul li.current a:hover { color: #ba4040; position:relative;z-index:5;}

#top_slider{overflow:hidden;position:relative;z-index:0;left:0px;height:963px;top:-250px; margin:0px auto;
background:url('http://wheresuccessblooms.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/WhereSuccessBlooms/images/slide_1.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
```

Comment: Please add a code example in your post, so that other user's can benefit from your question later on.

Comment: Added the CSS and HTML for reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your z-index looks like it's working fine to me. There does seem to be a positioning issue though. Set the top_slider div to `position:absolute` with `width:100%`. Or you can set `position:fixed` if you want it to stay put (also needs a width).

Comment: I am not sure if that is true because the background image is stopping at the right border of the menu. If I change the padding of the menu and add more right it pushes the background div to the right with it. If I delete it all together the background shows in the center perfectly. I will try the width and other settings you recommend.

Comment: Well crap that worked. haha. thanks for the information I guess I just don't understand why my method (as backward as it was) didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line after your `</nav>` tag

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```